# Congratulations to @ProfRob for reaching 100k reputation!

Tags: discussion, shoutout, reputation

## Congratulations!!!

I'm quite late to the party after a break from SE, and I've seen that @ProfRob has hit 100,000 reputation, a new milestone for our site!

Comment: In honor of this amazing contribution of effort and knowledge to this site we can [check if ProfRob has answered some of our questions that we haven’t yet accepted](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/773/7982).

Comment: Thank you for putting so much time and effort into astronomy.se and showing that the internet is good for more than just fake news and cat videos.

Comment: Bit late to this one, but as a newcomer to this astronomy.SE, I want to say I feel extremely lucky to have someone who is so knowledgeable, good at explaining and willing to dedicate so much time to helping others learn about astronomy. Thanks.